# how do I add a shadow on the floor of a tracking scene?

Tags: animation, tracking, shadows

Im having trouble adding a shadow to my scene. I have one scene of the main object (pic 1)[image] and one scene with the ground (pic 2)[image: Pic 2]
But when I render them together, the result is just the main object with no floor or shadow.
When rendering the floor is invisible. Im using Blender render and I would prefer it to stay that way. If you need more information you can comment below. Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must search for: Shadow catcher.
The blender will improve it in future versions but today we have to use two objects as you did, render the object, the ground without the shadow and the ground with shadows then use the node editor to join all.
The main object in the Layer 1, the ground in the second Layer.
See it bellow...(names in Portugese, my main language)
 [image]